# Android-SoftKeyboard leaving White space on hiding

Tags: android, android-view, android-softkeyboard, android-theme, android-actionbar-compat

I have an `Activity(FirstActivity)` which displays some content and at the top. I have a search field like actionbar searchview.

When i click that search icon, i am starting another activity i.e., `SecondAcitivity`, where i am performing search action(i.e.,by entering/changing text in edittext i am updating recyclerview).

I have to show the translucent behavior in my second activity i.e.,While typing values in Edittext , list should update at the same time in the background First activity content should be visible in transparent manner.So i have applied translucent theme for my second activity.

The problem is, i am observing white space on hiding the keyboard in SecondActivity.If i remove translucent theme then it's fine not getting any white space on closing the keyboard.
But i need the behavior of translucent theme.Can any one know the solution? please help me.

The code i have used for theme in styles is

```
<style name="Theme.AppCompat.Translucent"  parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/trans_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@android:style/Animation</item>
</style>
```